# Как сделать из многомерного массива несколько select'ов?

Tags: массивы, php, html, select

имеется такой массив

```
    $DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source']= array(
    1 => array(
        'name'=>'Заявка с сайта'),
    //если ключ 2 то'Входящий звонок',
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Входящий звонок',
        'items' => array(
            0 =>'По рекомендации',
            1 =>'По наклейке',
            2 =>'По рекламе',
            3 =>'С сайта'
            ),
        ),

    // 3 => 'Знакомство на мероприятии',
    3 => array(
        'name' => 'Знакомство на мероприятии',
        'items' =>array(
            0 =>'Собственное мероприятие',
            1 =>'Внешнее мероприятие'
            ),
        ),
    // 4 => 'Исходящий звонок',
    4 =>array(
        'name' =>'Исходящий звонок',
        'items' => array(
            0 =>'По своим связям',
            1 =>'По базе'
            ),  
        ),
    5 => array(
        'name'=>'Передача Партнером'
        ),
    6 => array(
        'name'=>'Трендер'
        ),
    );
```

вот так вот/ я пытаюсь сделать второй селект- но ничего не получается.
**По сути надо сделать 1 селект по всем name  и для каждого подмассива items  новые но как -чего от не получается**

```
<select>
<?php 
echo $DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'][1];
foreach ($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $key =>$value):?>
    <option value="<?=$key?>" ><?=$value['name'] ?> </option>
        <?php endforeach; 
        ?>
        </select>
        <select>
<?
foreach ($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $key =>$value):?>
<? foreach ($value as $key2 =>$value2):?>
    <? if(array_key_exists('items',$DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'][$key]))
        {

        }
    else
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?=$key2?>"> <?=$value2['items']?></option>
        <?php
        }
        endforeach;endforeach;
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: вообще-то вы тут чего-то мутного написали. Если разобрать последний код то получается что вы в селекте пытаетесь вставить еще селект. (прям в его коде). Такая иерархия недопустима. Вы бы словами описали что вы именно хотите получить, т.е. как вы видите это на словах а не на вашем коде.

Comment: надо сделать чтобы  из первого родительского массива выходили дочерние массивы(item) и каждый в своем селекте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы проходить по дочерним масивам

```
<? foreach ($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'][2]['items'] as $key2 =>$value2):?>
                <option value="<?=$key2?>"> <?=$value2?></option>
        <?
        endforeach;
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

> По сути надо сделать 1 селект по всем
> name

Если надо сделать один сгруппированный массив:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $el){
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$el['name'].'">';
        if(isset($el['items'])){
        foreach($el['items'] as $k => $v){
            echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</optgroup>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

> дочерние массивы(item) и каждый в
> своем селекте

Если всё-таки разбить на разные селекты:

```
foreach($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $el){
    if(isset($el['items'])){
        echo '<select>';
        foreach($el['items'] as $k => $v){
            echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

как-то пытался я такое сделать с помощью рекурсии но для категорий 
на чистом php не вышло пришлось с jquery делать

создаёте родительский массив ,проверяете ключи от дочерних элементов 
и вставляете в родительский массив дальше вывод.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно вас понял, то задача абсолютно банальна и тривиальна

```
<select>
<? foreach($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $category): ?>
    <option> <?= $category['name'] ?> </option>
<? endforeach; ?>
</select>

<? foreach($DEALER_MARKETING_INFORMATION['source'] as $category):
    if (!isset($category['items'])) continue; ?>        
    <select>
    <? foreach($category['items'] as $item): ?>
        <option><?= $item ?></option>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<? endforeach; ?>
```